# best way to add button control to listview or use datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to add button functionality to a listview and don't know where to begin. I currently have a listview that is populated from sql server query. I would like to add a button for each of the items added to the listview. Is this possible? I also see there is a datagridview but I am not sure how to populate the columns the same way as the listview or can I not? It would seem that the datagrid view is the better way to go as it has a button column build into it. So I am here to ask for some direction/guidance. Thank you (I am also still learning C# so please be kind!)

Current listview add items:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            //createButtons();

            if (row["NT"].ToString() == "C")
            {
                conSpell.Text = row["full_name_ro"].ToString();
            }
            if (row["NT"].ToString() == "N")
            {
                if (!multipleNs)
                {
                    apvSpell.Text = row["full_name_ro"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    apvSpell.Text += Environment.NewLine + row["full_name_ro"].ToString();
                }

                multipleNs = true;
            }
            if (row["NT"].ToString() == "V" ) //&& 
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row["Full_Name_ro"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["ADM1 Name"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["DSG"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["Feature Designation Name"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["UFI"].ToString());

                //add items to listView box
                listVariants.Items.Add(item);
                //Sort Items
                listVariants.Sorting = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending;

            }
```

I thought something like this would work for the datagridview but with no luck:

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
 dataGridView1.DataMember = "full_name_ro";
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Button b = new Button();
listVariants.Controls.Add(b);
```

Are you trying to accomplish something similar to this?

In a DataGridView, I am not too sure if you could add a button to it. In DataGridView there is the ability to have the rows / columns be event clicks, where when you click on a certain cell it has the ability to determine which section was selected. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, but how do I get it into its own column and so that it relates to each row or added item?

Comment: Does it have to be an actual button or just a selection of the entire row? 

A possible fix would have a single button, where once the button is clicked it grabs which row is selected. For example: First select the row you want, Second click a single button to handle the action. If that makes any sense.

Comment: I actually think I like that option. It's essentially the same idea. Which leads me to my next issue is how to populate the datagridview with only my selected columns from the query.

Comment: Go ahead and follow this tutorial http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to Winform, The ListView itself (or ListViewItem) does not function as a container of any kind so no way to add controls directly, however it is doable.

[Controls inside ListBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9188/Embedding-Controls-in-a-ListView)

Comment: I just added a checkbox to the listview and I am able to accomplish what I need with that. Thanks for the link!